# Load system dll : LoadLibrary("user32.dll") fails on Win7(32/64), but XP is OK?

Tags: dll, windows-7, loadlibrary

I have a problem using loadlibray to load a system dll: user32.dll on Win7. (Xp is Ok)

The demo is built on XP with VS2008， and runs successfully on XP. But, when it runs on Win7,  it crashes. I used the debugger, and find loadlibrary fails.

- The result of LoadLibrary : 0x0000000
- The result of GetLastError : 998(0x3E6)

Any tips on how to find the meaning of: 998?

Comment: You didn't copy user32.dll to that machine, did you?  The generic explanation is that your startup code is corrupting the heap.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the meaning of the error codes, go here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The error is:

> ERROR_NOACCESS: Invalid access to memory location.

Seems like something is attempting to access unmapped memory under Win7, but not under WinXP.  Strange.

Comment: Yes, the 998 is as you said. For the detail about this error code, here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196069